# Injective morphisms of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

When $X_1 \rightarrow Y$ and $X_2 \rightarrow Y$ are both injective morphisms of varieties such that they have the same image, are $X_1$ and $X_2$ then isomorphic? If not, please give an interesting additional assumption under which it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. The reason is that the morphisms need not be isomorphisms onto their image, even though they are injective. That is, they need not be closed immersions.

Here's an example of when it fails. Let $Y=\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$. Then if $X_1=V(y^2-x^3)\subset Y$ and $X_2\simeq \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is the normalisation of $X_1$, the normalisation morphism $X_2\to X_1$ is bijective. Composing it with the closed immersion $X_1\to Y$ we obtain a morphism $X_2\to Y$ with image $X_1$.